# Creating A New Entity And Calling SaveChanges To Save It Back To Database MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the code below I am trying to a new Facility to my Facilities table. the "Save" method calls DbContext SaveChanges(). After SaveChanges() executes I would expect newFacility to have an Id generated for it but it does not and it does not save to the database either. Is there something wrong with the way I am adding a new Facility to the Facilities DbSet maybe?

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(CreateFacilityViewModel viewModel)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var facilities = _db.Facilities;
                    var newFacility = new Facility();

                    //newFacility.FacilityId = viewModel.FacilityId;
                    newFacility.FaclityName = viewModel.FaclityName;
                    newFacility.Address = viewModel.Address;
                    newFacility.City = viewModel.City;
                    newFacility.State = viewModel.State;

                    _db.Facilities.ToList().Add(newFacility);

                    _db.Save();

                    return RedirectToAction("detail", "facility", new { id = newFacility.FacilityId });
                }
                return View(viewModel);
            }
```

Facilities Looks like this..

```
 public DbSet<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
  IQueryable<Facility> IGolfDataSource.Facilities
        {
            get { return Facilities; }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
_db.Facilities.ToList().Add(newFacility);
```

When you call ToList it is creating a new list in memory, then you add your new facility to the new, in memory list. Instead you want to add the new Facility directly into the DbSet:

```
_db.Facilities.Add(newFacility);
```

Comment: Add is not available on Facilities

Comment: Optionally, if you don't want to expose Facilities as a DbSet. You can create an AddFacility method on _db. In the AddFacility Method you can access the DbSet<Facilities> and use it's Add method.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
_db.Facilities.ToList().Add(newFacility);
```

To

```
_db.Facilities.Add(newFacility);
```

You want to add the object to the context, not to a list.

Comment: If Add is not available on Facilities, then you need to change the type of Facilities on _db. It should be exposed as a DbSet.

Comment: I am exposing a DbSet by returning IQueryable. Please see code above

Comment: you need to change IQueryable<Facility> to DbSet<Facility> then the add will work.